# Referencing Three.js in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am using c9.io, an IDE to code and quickly run a site to test your code. I have tried importing this outside of c9, and it still does not work. (I know it isn't a script error related to three.js itself.) In my HTML, I have this snippet:

```
<body>
   <script src='three.min.js'></script>
   <script src='scene1.js'></script>
</body>
```

I require the THREE namespace in my scene1 JavaScript like this:

```
import THREE from "three.min.js";
```

Is this all correct? Someone has tested this code, and said it worked. I have no folders in my hierarchy, just the three.min.js script, the scene1.js script, and my HTML script. Can anyone spot my error out?

Comment: I posted your "fixed" comment into an answer. You can mark it as accepted to show the problem is solved. Note in Stack Overflow changing the title to "solved" is not what we do; instead, we either post an answer of select the one that solved our issue.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the script in the header works just fine, despite every tutorial and the three.js docs saying it should be in the body.

Answer (score 0):

you can add three.js in html by:
search cdnjs threejs.
click the cdnjs website.
select latest threejs version from dropdown list with asset type javascript.
copy any one of the urls and use it in `<script src="that url"></script>`for e.g:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.149.0/three.min.js" integrity="sha512-6p9lGA4Cm89KiwN1CixiOVQU2H9e13LeYoN6/Hj/qoUhtrMW5vNiqQz9Z96Z7/I8u89ghL6SPBz9na5HFVzF3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```